# Bokeh plot displaying without data

Tags: python, bokeh

I am running the following code to render a plot with dates in the x axis and floats in the y axis:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.charts import Bar, Line, show
def datetime(x):
    return pd.DataFrame(x, dtype='datetime64')

openxbids = pd.read_csv('data')
openxbids.sort_values('date')

output_file("lines.html")

p = figure(width=800, height=250, x_axis_type="datetime")

p.line(datetime(openxbids['date']), openxbids['bids'], color = 'navy', alpha=0.5)

show(p)
```

However, when I run this, I get a graph without any data plotted.  The x and y axis ranges seem to be correctly detected.  What am I missing?

Comment: Are there any messages in the browser javascript console? What is the size of these data series?

Comment: There are no errors in the console.  The data series has 31 entries (all days in January + 1st day of Febuary).  Each date is of the form ' 2017-01-01' or 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Comment: best guess is you are setting `x` coords as an *entire* dataframe. Probably needs to be a single column from a dataframe, or a numpy array. Not sure why it would not complain, though. I'd actually reccommed a GH issue for this.